# Работа в api в Android

Tags: android, api

Добрый день, изучая книгу Пола Дейтела прочитал главу по API однако при реализации примера из книги не выводиться List_item

Прощу помощи почему - проверял код уже несколько раз, в конце даже перекопировал с примера книги

1. ошибка была в формировании строки к веб службе (видать сайт сменил за время выпуска книги)
2. найти не могу

MainActivity

```
package com.example.delari.weatherviewer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// List of Weather objects representing the forecast
private List<Weather> weatherList = new ArrayList<>();

// ArrayAdapter for binding Weather objects to a ListView
private WeatherArrayAdapter weatherArrayAdapter;
private ListView weatherListView; // displays weather info

// configure Toolbar, ListView and FAB
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // autogenerated code to inflate layout and configure Toolbar
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // create ArrayAdapter to bind weatherList to the weatherListView
    weatherListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.weatherListView);
    weatherArrayAdapter = new WeatherArrayAdapter(this, weatherList);
    weatherListView.setAdapter(weatherArrayAdapter);

    // configure FAB to hide keyboard and initiate web service request
    FloatingActionButton fab =
            (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // get text from locationEditText and create web service URL
            EditText locationEditText =
                    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationEditText);
            URL url = createURL(locationEditText.getText().toString());

            // hide keyboard and initiate a GetWeatherTask to download
            // weather data from OpenWeatherMap.org in a separate thread
            if (url != null) {
                dismissKeyboard(locationEditText);
                GetWeatherTask getLocalWeatherTask = new GetWeatherTask();
                getLocalWeatherTask.execute(url);
            }
            else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                        R.string.invalid_url, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

// programmatically dismiss keyboard when user touches FAB
private void dismissKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

// create openweathermap.org web service URL using city
private URL createURL(String city) {
    String apiKey = getString(R.string.api_key);
    String baseUrl = getString(R.string.web_service_url);

    try {
        // create URL for specified city and imperial units (Fahrenheit)
        String urlString = baseUrl + "1486209" +
                "&units=imperial&cnt=16&APPID=" + apiKey;
        return new URL(urlString);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null; // URL was malformed
}

// makes the REST web service call to get weather data and
// saves the data to a local HTML file
private class GetWeatherTask
        extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
            int response = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {

                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                            R.string.read_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            }
            else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                        R.string.connect_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                    R.string.connect_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            connection.disconnect(); // close the HttpURLConnection
        }

        return null;
    }

    // process JSON response and update ListView
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject weather) {
        convertJSONtoArrayList(weather); // repopulate weatherList
        weatherArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // rebind to ListView
        weatherListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0); // scroll to top
    }
}

// create Weather objects from JSONObject containing the forecast
private void convertJSONtoArrayList(JSONObject forecast) {
    weatherList.clear(); // clear old weather data

    try {
        // get forecast's "list" JSONArray
        JSONArray list = forecast.getJSONArray("list");

        // convert each element of list to a Weather object
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject day = list.getJSONObject(i); // get one day's data

            // get the day's temperatures ("temp") JSONObject
            JSONObject temperatures = day.getJSONObject("temp");

            // get day's "weather" JSONObject for the description and icon
            JSONObject weather =
                    day.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);

            // add new Weather object to weatherList
            weatherList.add(new Weather(
                    day.getLong("dt"), // date/time timestamp
                    temperatures.getDouble("min"), // minimum temperature
                    temperatures.getDouble("max"), // maximum temperature
                    day.getDouble("humidity"), // percent humidity
                    weather.getString("description") // weather conditions
                    ));
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Weather

```
package com.example.delari.weatherviewer;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

class Weather {
    public final String dayOfWeek;
    public final String minTemp;
    public final String maxTemp;
    public final String humidity;
    public final String description;


    // constructor
    public Weather(long timeStamp, double minTemp, double maxTemp,
                   double humidity, String description) {
        // NumberFormat to format double temperatures rounded to integers
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);

        this.dayOfWeek = convertTimeStampToDay(timeStamp);
        this.minTemp = numberFormat.format(minTemp) + "\u00B0F";
        this.maxTemp = numberFormat.format(maxTemp) + "\u00B0F";
        this.humidity =
                NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(humidity / 100.0);
        this.description = description;
    }

    // convert timestamp to a day's name (e.g., Monday, Tuesday, ...)
    private static String convertTimeStampToDay(long timeStamp) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // create Calendar
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp * 1000); // set time
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); // get device's time zone

        // adjust time for device's time zone
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,
                tz.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

        // SimpleDateFormat that returns the day's name
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        return dateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
}
```

ArrayAdapter

```
package com.example.delari.weatherviewer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class WeatherArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather> {
    // class for reusing views as list items scroll off and onto the screen
    private static class ViewHolder {

        TextView dayTextView;
        TextView lowTextView;
        TextView hiTextView;
        TextView humidityTextView;
    }

    // stores already downloaded Bitmaps for reuse
    private Map<String, Bitmap> bitmaps = new HashMap<>();

    // constructor to initialize superclass inherited members
    public WeatherArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Weather> forecast) {
        super(context, -1, forecast);
    }

    // creates the custom views for the ListView's items
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get Weather object for this specified ListView position
        Weather day = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder viewHolder; // object that reference's list item's views

        // check for reusable ViewHolder from a ListView item that scrolled
        // offscreen; otherwise, create a new ViewHolder
        if (convertView == null) { // no reusable ViewHolder, so create one
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView =
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder.dayTextView =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
            viewHolder.lowTextView =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lowTextView);
            viewHolder.hiTextView =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hiTextView);
            viewHolder.humidityTextView =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.humidityTextView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else { // reuse existing ViewHolder stored as the list item's tag
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // if weather condition icon already downloaded, use it;
        // otherwise, download icon in a separate thread


        // get other data from Weather object and place into views
        Context context = getContext(); // for loading String resources
        viewHolder.dayTextView.setText(context.getString(
                R.string.day_description, day.dayOfWeek, day.description));
        viewHolder.lowTextView.setText(
                context.getString(R.string.low_temp, day.minTemp));
        viewHolder.hiTextView.setText(
                context.getString(R.string.high_temp, day.maxTemp));
        viewHolder.humidityTextView.setText(
                context.getString(R.string.humidity, day.humidity));

        return convertView; // return completed list item to display
    }

    // AsyncTask to load weather condition icons in a separate thread

}
```

MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.delari.weatherviewer.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/view">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_text"
            android:id="@+id/locationEditText"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/weatherListView"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/dayTextView"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="LargeText"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lowTextView"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hiTextView"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/humidityTextView"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ListItem явно неверный

Comment: Можно более точнее? вроде указывается через Id однако при нажатии на кнопку должно происходить появление списка - а его нет

Comment: Я лишь указываю на то, что последние куски кода идентичны. Наверное вы опечатались. По смой проблеме не скажу - кода слишком много.

Comment: понял, подправил - опечатался

Comment: GridLayout внутри ячейки списка - странное решение. Попробуйте сначала просто TextView отобразить. Возможно в этом проблема

Comment: она нужна для добавления колон и строк, если ее убрать брать только LargeText

Comment: Попробуйте в коструктор супер класса адаптера передать вашу разметку: `super(context, R.layout.list_item, forecast);`

Comment: также, после нажатия на кнопку list_item не появляется

Comment: Ну, тут только и остаётся что пытаться локализовать проблему. Пройдитесь по каждому шагу и выясните, отправляется ли запрос, получается ли ответ, парсится ли JSON, сетятся ли распаршенные данные в адаптер etc. Тогда можно будет удалить 90% вашего кода из вопроса (т.к. тут явно много лишнего, не относящегося к реальной проблеме) и станет понятно где у вас ошибка. Сами мы не сможем найти время чтобы ваш код у себя компилировать и отлаживать.

Comment: Да вроде парситься, не работает именно отображение данных

Comment: А что именно не работает? Вы пробовали просто массив строк отобразить так? Попробуйте это сделать, а потом пошагово усложнять - так увидите на каком шаге у вас перестаёт это работать

Comment: как результат колупания, оказалось что получаемый объект тоже был изменен в итоге пришлось переписывать сам конвертор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделав нечто подобное

```
JSONArray list = forecast.getJSONArray("list");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject day = list.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject temp =
                        day.getJSONObject("main");
                weatherList.add(new Weather(
                        day.getLong("dt"),
                        temp.getDouble("temp_min"),
                        temp.getDouble("temp_max"),
                        0.0,
                        ""
                        ));
}
```

стал получать данные в item_list